# Why are there lifetime/type mismatch errors when forwarding a reference through a lambda?

Tags: rust, lambda

I was recently trying to implement a system which allowed for magic type params per 
[rust-magic-function-params](https://github.com/alexpusch/rust-magic-function-params), with the addition that the params could be borrowed from the `Context` object. I built a version of this, with an additional `Executor` type which can call the `Handler`s in a generic, type erased way [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8f8ff0070a0740d21ea782eed8749ba4):

Going through the link, here are the most important parts of the example:

```
trait Handler<'a, T: 'a>: 'static {
    fn call(&self, value: T) -> Result<(), Error>;
}

impl<'a, T: 'a, F> Handler<'a, T> for F
where
    F: Fn(T) -> Result<(), Error> + 'static,
{
    fn call(&self, value: T) -> Result<(), Error> {
        (self)(value)
    }
}
```

The `Handler` trait is responsible for calling the function. It also has a new lifetime parameter `'a`, which the `value` parameter in `call()` must live for.

```
trait Param<'a>: Sized + 'a {
    fn from_state(state: &'a HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>) -> Result<Self, Error>;
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, Hash, Ord, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
struct StateVar<'a, T: ?Sized>(&'a T);

impl<'a, T: Any> Param<'a> for StateVar<'a, T> {
    fn from_state(state: &'a HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        state
            .get(&TypeId::of::<T>())
            .and_then(|any| any.downcast_ref::<T>().map(StateVar))
            .ok_or_else(|| Error::from("Parameter not present"))
    }
}
```

The `Param<'a>` trait is used to create an instance of a variable from the `state`, which can then be passed to a `Handler`'s parameter (similar to the `FromContext` trait in the `axum` example linked above. The `StateVar<'a, T>` implements the `Param<'a>` trait for getting references from the `state`.

```
struct ErasedHandler(Box<dyn Fn(&HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>) -> Result<(), Error>>);

#[derive(Default)]
struct Executor {
    handlers: Vec<ErasedHandler>,
    state: HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>,
}

impl Executor {
    #[allow(unused)]
    fn add_handler<'a, H, T>(&mut self, handler: H)
    where
        T: Param<'a> + 'a,
        H: Handler<'a, T>,
    {
        // ...
    }

    fn add_var<T: Any>(&mut self, value: T) {
        self.state.insert(TypeId::of::<T>(), Box::new(value));
    }

    fn run(&self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        for handler in &self.handlers[..] {
            (handler.0)(&self.state)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

The `ErasedHandler` holds a type erased handler wrapped in a boxed lambda. The `Executor` struct holds all registered handlers, as well as the state. The `add_var()` method adds a `StateVar`, and the `run()` method runs all handlers using the contained `state`.

The implementation of `Executor::add_handler` is:

```
impl Executor {
    fn add_handler<'a, H, T>(&mut self, handler: H)
    where
        T: Param<'a> + 'a,
        H: Handler<'a, T>,
    {
        fn make_wrapper<'a_, H_, T_>(
            handler: H_,
        ) -> Box<dyn Fn(&'a_ HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>) -> Result<(), Error>>
        where
            T_: Param<'a_> + 'a_,
            H_: Handler<'a_, T_>,
        {
            Box::new(move |state: &'a_ HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>| {
                T_::from_state(state).and_then(|param| handler.call(param))
            })
        }

        let wrapper = make_wrapper::<'a, H, T>(handler);
        self.handlers.push(ErasedHandler(wrapper));
    }
}
```

where it moves the `handler` into a boxed wrapper lambda, and then adds it to its `handlers` `Vec`.

This system can then be called as demonstrated in the `main` function:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    fn my_handler(StateVar(value): StateVar<'_, i32>) -> Result<(), Error> {
        println!("Stored state value = {value}");
        Ok(())
    }

    let mut executor = Executor::default();
    executor.add_var::<i32>(42);
    executor.add_handler(my_handler);

    executor.run()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Where any number of variables (of unique types) and `handler`s can be added to run sequentially. When this `main` function is run, it should ideally print:

```
Stored state value = 42
```

However, attempting to run this program results in a compile error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:67:42
   |
49 |     fn add_handler<'a, H, T>(&mut self, handler: H)
   |                    -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
67 |         self.handlers.push(ErasedHandler(wrapper));
   |                                          ^^^^^^^ cast requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:67:42
   |
67 |         self.handlers.push(ErasedHandler(wrapper));
   |                                          ^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected trait object `dyn for<'a> Fn(&'a HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>`
              found trait object `dyn Fn(&HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 2 previous errors
```

These errors are confusing (to me), and I'm not sure how to solve them. Is it possible to write the API in a way that the handler parameters could be borrowed from `State`, or do they have to be `Clone`d?

Deleting this line causes the compile error to disappear, but it means that no `Handler`s will be added to the `Executor`, and the message won't be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done.

I'm not so sure what the first error says, but the second error says that `ErasedHandle` is expected to contain a function that can take `&'lifetime HashMap` for *any* lifetime (`for<'lifetime> &'lifetime HashMap`), but you're actually giving it a closure that can take only `&'a HashMap` for the specific lifetime `'a` defined in `add_handler()`.

Another way to read it is: what is `'a`? we call the handlers inside `run()` with the lifetime of `&self`, but this is the lifetime of `&self` **of `run()`**, and it doesn't exist when we call `add_handler()` before that.

We need a higher-ranked lifetime, but we unfortunately cannot specify it, I will explain why briefly (because a long explanation will be... long). It is tempting to get rid of `'a` and just specify `T: for<'a> Param<'a>`, but both if we specify `H: for<'a> Handler<'a, T>` or if we just get rid of `'a` in `Handler`, we hit an uncrossable obstacle: we cannot capture in the type system that we want a closure with HRTB lifetime, that is that takes `for<'a> &'a Foo`, all we can do is `&'a Foo` for some specific lifetime `'a`.